# Accessing variable value by string name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Issue: I want to access some variables I got in my js-file by a string.

I know there is an option to receive variable value if you have an object and pass the object key name in square brackets to the object, but this is not the case here. Here I have just one comon variable, and I want its value by "sending" a string down.

Example on what I want to achieve:

```
const constantName = 12345; // Value to access
const stringToUseToGetTheValueOfConstantName = 'constantName';

// I want to know how to get the '12345' by something like this:
const valueFinallyAccessed = `${stringToUseToGetTheValueOfConstantName}`; // I know this returns a string
console.log(valueFinallyAccessed); // 12345
```

**Solution**

```
const valueFinallyAccessed = eval(stringToUseToGetTheValueOfConstantName);
console.log(valueFinallyAccessed); // Prints out the value 12345
```

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: @HarunYilmaz - works with `var` not with `const` or `let` - unless `eval` is the answer

Comment: I didn't try it. I just wanted to share a similar question.

Comment: I added to the comment - `eval` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you so much, the eval suggestion did work perfectly! I will update my question with the solution